# Scaling icons/logo at run time in order to support multiple screens- Android

Tags: android, image

I am in the process of creating an android app. However, supporting multiple screens seems to be an issue in app development. The ways I have seen that Android says to support multiple screens, is to provide duplicates of icons/logos of different sizes. However, I find this to be an inadequate solution and am convinced that there has to be a better way.

I am storing my icons/logos in a folder on my server. These images will be 1024 by 1024 images. I want to be able to retrieve the logo/icon from the server and scale the images at run time to the screen being supported. I know there has to be a way to do this.

Solutions?

Comment: it should really just work by default. if you have an imageview, just set its size in the layout xml and when you setBitmap of the imageview it should scale the image to the size of the imageview

Comment: Is this what works for you, i.e. quality and consistency between screen sizes?

Comment: yea. i have never had issues with doing it that way.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the tip. Although, it doesn't really make that much sense considering Android telling users to provide multiple images of different sizes. Conversely though, it does make sense that the app should re-size on its on.

Comment: You can provide the highest resolution images (xxxhdpi) only. They will be rescaled as per the missing drawable folder required by the current screen density. Scaling **down** is preferrable for a better quality.

Comment: Der Golem, you are recommending just providing the largest size image (for me approx 1024 x 1024) for the app in the drawables folder? And then simply allow android to automatically rescale the images for me, or using bitmap.createScaled Bitmap and scale depending on the screen?

Comment: Android will scale it automatically. But 1024x1024 seems way too big, to me.

Answer (score 0):

I allways scale my bitmaps depending on the Width and Height of the SurfaceView I am drawing to. The Bitmap class has some methods to provide such functionality.

Either you load your images into Bitmaps and scale them afterwards or you can use Bitmap.Options and load directly from the assets in your desired sizes!

Check the Bitmap, BitmapFactory , SurfaceView and Canvas API's

Here's an example out of one of my apps:

```
playTable.dotSymbol=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(origDotBitmap,playTable.symbolSize,playTable.symbolSize,true);
```

it's just an icon that i scale from a given bitmap i have loaded before:

```
origDotBitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res,R.drawable.dotobject);
```

Also:beware of OutOfMemory Exception...on my note 4 i can Load 28 or so bitmaps of the size of 1024x1024 before OOM

Comment: In using the Bitmap.createScaledBitmap method, how is the quality of the images after resizing? Also, good tip on the OutOfMemoryException. Did this exception arise due to you storing the images in the drawable folder, or from downloading from a remote source?

Comment: it comes when you load too amny bitmaps into ram so it flows over...you can store up to 2 GB in your apk, it just comes down to OOM when you load too much into the memory. The quality depends on the original size of the Bitmap you are scaling from...loading bitmaps into memory and resizing them after is dangerous...its better to load it directly with options so you can provide a 5000x5000 px image and load it with the minimum of loss and aliasing into your desired size...but the bigger the image the more time it takes to load it!

Comment: as you download it you must first store the images in your ram so i would load image after image and resize them as i want then call the GC and load the next one

Answer (score 0):

Following the described paradigm of providing multiple images in buckets (ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, tvdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, xxxhdpi and etc.) is perhaps the safest and simplest bet.

However, providing drawables only for some buckets, let's say only for xxhdpi, will do the trick and rescale images for other non-xxhdpi devices. But note, there is no guarantee that images will appear in exactly the same way as they are supposed.

Considering the solution on pulling images from the network and rescaling them (assuming based on computed width of the screen), please consider the following potential issues:
 1. will the quality of the provided image guarantee proper scaling on extra large devices?
 2. pulling images from network is an expensive call which shouldn't be run on a main thread, so you'd have to pull them asynchronously
 3. To my knowledge, the exact width of the screen will be known only once the layouts are placed on the screen, therefore, you'd have to observe OnGlobalLayoutListener. This, in conjunction with the asynchronous request to pull the image from the network, potentially creates a race condition you'd have to take care of.

Issue 2 an 3 can be somewhat simplified by using Volley's ImageLoader and NetworkImageView (https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request.html) or any other similar library.

Comment: Volley seems like a very useful tool. If not for this specific project, then in the future. After looking over your link, it seems like volley abstracts the http request away (besides providing the url). Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, besides the URL, the only thing you need to provide is the ImageLoader object which can also take care of caching.

So a typical usage looks like:
String url = "http://somepic.png"
NetworkImageView mNetworkImageView = (NetworkImageView) findViewById(R.id.someimage);
mNetworkImageView.setImageUrl(url, mImageLoader);